# Firefox Quantum - I want to access restricted port but `network.security.ports.banned.override` does not work?

Tags: firefox, firefox-57

Firefox Quantum - I want to access restricted port but `network.security.ports.banned.override` does not seem to work.

How can I connect to http://localhost:4045 ?

Answer (score 18):

You can add this as String.

Go to the address field (where you type `www.google.com`) and type `about:config`.

Now right click on the list and select New > String.

Give it a name, in this case `network.security.ports.banned.override`, and enter the port, port range, or comma-separated ports. To allow all ports, simply type `1-65535` as the value. To allow just a few ports, enter `87,88,89,1050` etc.

Firefox 57 doesn't contain `network.security.ports.banned.override` by default, but you can still add it manually.

Comment: I can confirm that this works.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to enter a range. I thought it only worked with a comma-separated series before.